# How was the Vengeance able to "catch up" to the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

In *Star Trek Into Darkness*, the Vengeance was able to catch up to the Enterprise and attack it while in warp.

According to the [answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48915/when-a-ship-drops-out-of-warp-does-it-retain-the-speed-it-was-at-when-it-entered), warp is a bubble around a specific ship. This would explain why Kirk was so surprised when it happened.

**How was the Vengeance able to catch up, or get into the Enterprise’s warp bubble?**

Comment: If it were like you say, then ships would never have to worry about attacks.   Just go to warp and you are safe.   Obviously all kinds of precedent shows this is not the case.

Comment: i believe that they were safe in warp up until tos movies, or TNG. it was a new more advanced tech at the time  it was introduced in the new alternate universe.

Comment: They followed the trail of lens flare.

Comment: Why would the Vengeance need to get into the Enterprise's warp bubble? As long as they were both traveling at the same warp speed and were near each other, they should be able to see each other at warp speed even if in their own separate warp bubbles, since you can still see the outside universe from inside a warp bubble, it's not like a parallel dimension. As far as how it was able to catch up, maybe it just had engines capable of a higher maximum warp factor?

Comment: you can merge into another ships warp bubble, this was seen in one of the last episode of enterprise, they expanded their warp bubbles so the 2 ships shared the same bubble, and then they literally left the ship and crossed through space on a ladder or rope, and got onto the other ship. while moving at warp.

Comment: It has been shown, on multiple occasions, that two ships travelling at warp speed can fire upon and otherwise engage each other, notably in "Arena" and "The Corbomite Manoeuvre." The concept of a mysterious "warp bubble" was a meaningless and unnecessary addition such as the need for a big drill to drop red matter in Abrams' first film.

Comment: @JamesSheridan See TNG 4x05, [Remember Me](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Remember_Me_(episode)), for an episode all about a warp bubble

Comment: @Izkata: Yes, but that warp bubble experiment had absolutely nothing to do with the regular mode of warp travel used by the Federation and other Alpha Quadrant polities. It certainly had nothing to do with *TOS*-era warp travel.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Then [see the images here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_field) as well - the warp field has always had a bubble-like shape around the ship, and this question using "bubble" is based on another answer that described it as such

Comment: @James Sheridan - It may help to point out that *unlike* in "Remember Me", the warp bubble was typically not shown as isolating the ship from everything outside the bubble, they could still see outside and even fire on other ships in their own warp bubble, the point of the "bubble" was just that it could carry the ship along at faster-than-light speeds.

Comment: Warp bubble is sometimes called "warp field bubble". It is necessary for any ship to enter warp as stresses exerted on the hull at that speeds will be quickly destructive and of course it is what propels the starship.

Official name for warp drives were: "gravimetric field displacement manifold".
on the other Cochrane called his drive "continuum distortion propulsion".
According to theory warp field bubble should be if not impenetrable to then at least heavily attenuating any incoming fire.
And, of course phasers, being LIGHT SPEED WEAPONS should miss Enterprise completely.

Comment: @AcePL torpedos for example, use Warp Sustainer engines, that take some of the warp field bubble of the firing ship, to continue onto warp. And any species that can make a warp capable weapon, would be able to penetrate the field of another that way. And we also know that they can change the size of the warp bubble to include other ships inside of it. Manipulation of warp bubbles would be the very basis of any offensive technology and tactics.

Comment: @AcePL as for phasers, canon goes back and forth on whether they are light/em or plasma weapons (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Phaser).

Comment: @cde - well, torpedoes are one thing. Those you can evade... Phasers - no matter what they are - are still light speed weapon, no matter what base. There is theory that plasma is FTL, but only experiment I know of about is decades old and very... problematic, so for the time being let's skip this one. I mentioned phasers are LSW, not lasers. The LSW is the operative description. Once shot leaves warp bubble of one ship in high warp simply cannot reach another ship in high warp. no matter how close/far it is. Except for (canon) tachyons, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @AcePL hand waved. `According to page 84 of the DS9 Manual, a phaser beam can be delivered at warp speeds due to an annular confinement beam jacket and other advances in subspace technology.` Basically the same as the torpedos, a small warp field is projected around the phaser beam, allowing it to travel at warp speeds.

Comment: Cool. :) Comments withdrawn then. Thanks for that.

Comment: Remember that Enterprise takes place entirely on the Holodeck in the TNG era; the notion of merging warp bubbles is therefore not canon.

Comment: Having said that Jar Jar Abrams put R2D2 in Star Trek so the concept of canon is moot at this point.

Comment: @Gaius - there's still a question of whether the ENTIRE series was a holodeck recreation, or only that last episode. We may never know.

Answer (score 4):

The Enterprise had a slight head start, but the Vengeance was able to catch up to it because the Vengeance was travelling at a faster speed. Plain and simple.

Your point about the warp bubbles of the two ships is irrelevant.  As @Hypnosifl and @JamesSheridan mentioned in their comments below your question, there are many instances in Star Trek (across the series, across the films) where it is clearly shown that (a) a ship travelling at warp can see the immediate universe outside the bubble, and (b) that ships can exchange fire while at warp.  (Think about the desperate attempt to flee the Borg at the end of "[Q Who](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_Who_%28episode%29)".)  It might be interesting to compile all such instances...but perhaps only mildly so.

Star Trek may occur in a technologically-advanced future, but this particular topic is less to do with warp field mechanics and more to do with Newtonian kinematics (or even earlier, Aesop's "The Tortoise and the Hare" --- not directly analogous  to the Vengeance / Enterprise chase for obvious reasons, but lessons to be learned about speed and winning a race, nevertheless).

Answer (score -1):

If anybody was thinking why the vengeance was faster, it was because Khan had used technologies inside the ship to allow it to go to warp 10 and phasers that could fire at warp speed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any sources to support this?  Quotes?  Good answers should have supporting evidence, not just a few statements; please read [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Khan designed the engines for the Vengeance and he himself was advanced so he knew advanced technologies, and Khan did actually care very much for the 72 members of his family.

Comment: While interesting, this answer doesn't give much detail in how the ship itself was able to catch up to and attack the Enterprise while it was in warp.